# EC2 hosted service multi-tenant dynamic DNS solution

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, service, dynamic-dns

I want to change the model of my EC2 hosted service to have a separate sub domain for each tenant (ie. `<accountname>.example.com`). My primary DNS is now with dnsmadeeasy.com, but their [dynamic DNS offering](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/client.txt) seem pretty weak:

- it requires the API to use my full dnsmadeeasy.com account credentials, I rather have the API use a limited privilege credential that can only add/remove/modify subdomain records
- from what I gather it only allows to modify existing records, does not allow me to dynamically add/remove records for new tenant subdomains

My question what are my alternatives? Is there something in the dnsmadeeasy API offering I misunderstood and I should just use them? Is there some other similar DNS service that has a DDNS offering that satisfies my requirements? Or should I just bite the bullet and host my own DNS (my fear is not configuration/learning/know how, my fear is reliability).

If you recommend the latter, can you detail the necessary steps or a link to a good tutorial how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for http://www.ultradns.com. They have a nice API implemented and in some languages. It seems a good solution for you, matching your needs...

doc:

http://www.ultradns.net/api/NUS_API_XML.pdf

Perl implementation:

http://search.cpan.org/~timb/UltraDNS-0.06/

Hope that helps.